# Can't execute JavaVM->DetachCurrentThread(): "attempting to detach while still running code"

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, dalvik

I have an Android app that uses NDK - a regular Android Java app with regular UI and C++ core. There are places in the core where I need to call Java methods, which means I need a `JNIEnv*` for that thread, which in turn means that I need to call `JavaVM->AttachCurrentThread()` to get the valid `env`.

Previously, was just doing `AttachCurrentThread` and didn't bother to detach at all. It worked fine in Dalvik, but ART aborts the application as soon as a thread that has called `AttachCurrentThread` exits without calling `DetachCurrentThread`. So I've read the JNI reference, and indeed it says that I must call `DetachCurrentThread`. But when I do that, ART aborts the app with the following message:

> attempting to detach while still running code

What's the problem here, and how to call `DetachCurrentThread` properly?

Comment: Why not just use `JavaVM->GetEnv(void** penv, jint version);` to get `JNIEnv`?

Comment: @alijandro: If the current thread isn't attached to the VM, `GetEnv` will fail (it will return `JNI_EDETACHED` and give you a `NULL` `JNIEnv*`). However, it seems like a good idea to first call `GetEnv`, and only if it returns `JNI_EDETACHED` do you call `AttachCurrentThread`.

Comment: @Michael: That does seem like a good idea, thank you. On the other hand, though, JNI references explicitly states that calling `AttachCurrentThread` on an already attached thread is a no-op. So I assume `AttachCurrentThread` already does what you suggest.

Comment: Well, in some cases it's important to know whether `AttachCurrentThread` actually did attach the thread, so that you don't call `DetachCurrentThread` after a no-op attach. I ended up writing a C++ class that upon construction either obtains the `JNIEnv*` from `GetEnv` or `AttachCurrentThread`, and then calls `DetachCurrentThread` in the destructor only if the constructor had to call `AttachCurrentThread`. That way I can declare these objects, use their `JNIEnv*` and have the thread automatically be detached if needed when the object falls out of scope.

Comment: @Michael, you're right! That _might_ have been my mistake - multiple calls to `detach`. I think that shouldn't have happened, because every time I request the `JNIEnv*` I call `attach`, and when I'm done with it I call `detach` (by means of a C++ RAII-style wrapper around `JNIEnv*`). But I will try your approach, it's certainly safer and cleaner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dalvik will also abort if the thread exits without detaching.  This is implemented through a pthread key -- see `threadExitCheck()` in [Thread.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/Thread.cpp).

A thread may not detach unless its call stack is empty.  The reasoning behind this is to ensure that any resources like monitor locks (i.e. `synchronized` statements) are properly released as the stack unwinds.

The second and subsequent attach calls are, as defined by the spec, low-cost no-ops.  There's no reference counting, so detach always detaches, no matter how many attaches have happened.  One solution is to add your own reference-counted wrapper.

Another approach is to attach and detach every time.  This is used by the app framework on certain callbacks.  This wasn't so much a deliberate choice as a side-effect of wrapping Java sources around code developed primarily in C++, and trying to shoe-horn the functionality in.  If you look at [SurfaceTexture.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/core/jni/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.cpp), particularly `JNISurfaceTextureContext::onFrameAvailable()`, you can see that when SurfaceTexture needs to invoke a Java-language callback function, it will attach the thread, invoke the callback, and then if the thread was just attached it will immediately detach it.  The "needsDetach" flag is set by calling `GetEnv` to see if the thread was previously attached.

This isn't a great thing performance-wise, as each attach needs to allocate a Thread object and do some internal VM housekeeping, but it does yield the correct behavior.

Comment: So the `AttachCurrentThread` is not free in terms of performance? I might want to cache the `JNIEnv*` for each thread and look it up on subsequent calls, rather than do it every time. The problem with that, though, is that I don't know when to detach... This needs some thought.

Comment: The initial attach is not free. Once attached, any subsequent attach calls are essentially free. The difficulty in knowing when to detach is why the SurfaceTexture code will attach/detach every time if needed.  I think the problem there arose because the stagefright media player lib was posting video frames from a native thread it started... SurfaceTexture had no visibility into the thread's lifetime, so it couldn't attach it up front, and had no opportunity to detach it before the thread exited.  At 30fps the performance drag was acceptable, so there was no attempt to modify libstagefright.

Comment: This answer saved the day for me. And the links you referenced are great examples. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: As of Oreo, I'm seeing a lot of GC pressure due to SurfaceTexture's constant Attach/Detach on every frame. Is there any way to force the JNISurfaceTextureContext thread to bind a JNIEnv once (since it does seem to account for the case where it might be bound already and avoids detaching after every call)?

Comment: Did some more digging and found bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37079050 filed 1/2016 regarding poor performance of SurfaceTexture's onFrameAvailable listener.

Comment: @tmm1: the attach/detach is required if the thread executing the ST callback isn't already attached to the VM. You should post a new question explaining what you're trying to do at a higher level. It's possible that going about it differently would avoid the situation entirely.

Comment: I'm just trying to use SurfaceTexture, and noticing poor performance. Googling landed me here and I was able to confirm that the Attach/Detach happening inside SurfaceTexture.cpp is what's killing performance for me on Oreo. It doesn't seem like there's any way for me to work around the issue since it's happening in the platform code. I updated that Android issue I found in hopes that it can be fixed upstream.

Answer (score 7):

I'll try a direct and practical approach (with sample code, without use of classes) answering this question for the occasional developer that came up with this error in android, in cases where they had it working and after a OS or framework update (Qt?) it started to give problems with that error and message.

```
    JNIEXPORT void Java_com_package_class_function(JNIEnv* env.... {

        JavaVM* jvm;
        env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);

        JNIEnv* myNewEnv; // as the code to run might be in a different thread (connections to signals for example) we will have a 'new one'
        JavaVMAttachArgs jvmArgs;
        jvmArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;

        int attachedHere = 0; // know if detaching at the end is necessary
        jint res = jvm->GetEnv((void**)&myNewEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6); // checks if current env needs attaching or it is already attached
        if (JNI_EDETACHED == res) {
            // Supported but not attached yet, needs to call AttachCurrentThread
            res = jvm->AttachCurrentThread(reinterpret_cast<JNIEnv **>(&myNewEnv), &jvmArgs);
            if (JNI_OK == res) {
                attachedHere = 1;
            } else {
                // Failed to attach, cancel
                return;
            }
        } else if (JNI_OK == res) {
            // Current thread already attached, do not attach 'again' (just to save the attachedHere flag)
            // We make sure to keep attachedHere = 0
        } else {
            // JNI_EVERSION, specified version is not supported cancel this..
            return;
        }

        // Execute code using myNewEnv
        // ...

        if (attachedHere) { // Key check
            jvm->DetachCurrentThread(); // Done only when attachment was done here
        }
    }
```

Everything made sense after seeing the [The Invocation API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) for GetEnv:

> RETURNS:
>   If the current thread is not attached to the VM, sets *env to NULL, and returns JNI_EDETACHED. If the specified version is not supported, sets *env to NULL, and returns JNI_EVERSION. Otherwise, sets *env to the appropriate interface, and returns JNI_OK.

Credits to:
- This question [Getting error "attempting to detach while still running code" when calling JavaVm->DetachCurrentThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254587/getting-error-attempting-to-detach-while-still-running-code-when-calling-javav?noredirect=1&lq=1) that in its example made it clear that it was necessary to double check every time (even though before calling detach it doesn't do it).
- @Michael that in this question comments he notes it clearly about not calling detach.
- What @fadden said: "There's no reference counting, so detach always detaches, no matter how many attaches have happened."