# Why does my Android app crash when my threads exit?

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, stl, android-ndk

Why does my Android app crash when my threads exit?

In `logcat` I see the following output when my app crashes.

```
D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=1)
E/dalvikvm: threadid=13: native thread exited without detaching
E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
```

I am not sure what thread causes this. The app makes use of a C++ library with a few instances of STL threads (`std::thread`). Here is an example of how I work with threads in the library:

```
std::thread thread([context] () { ... });
thread.detach();
```

The library works without any such errors on iOS, OS X, and Linux. My guess is that the error is not because of a missing call to `std::thread::detach`.

Not sure if it is relevant:

- I use `gnustl_static`
- the library is integrated via NDK but the low level code is platform-independent so I am not calling `JavaVM::AttachCurrentThread` or `JavaVM::DetachCurrentThread`

I am not sure what to do or what to look for.

Comment: Looking at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534304/android-jni-call-attachcurrentthread-without-detachcurrentthread . Your logcat matches the error messages in the source for a thread exiting before detaching.  Sorry if this isn't helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, *something* is calling `AttachCurrentThread`.  If nothing were, the VM wouldn't be aware if the thread exited or not.

Any thread that makes JNI calls must first be attached to the VM.  Once attached, it must detach before exiting to avoid resource leaks.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534304/android-jni-call-attachcurrentthread-without-detachcurrentthread) has more information about the situation, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923917/cant-execute-javavm-detachcurrentthread-attempting-to-detach-while-still-r/) has some additional details.

Comment: Doh! You are right. One of the lower level threads called `AttachCurrentThread` indirectly. Thanks a lot!