# Getting error "attempting to detach while still running code" when calling JavaVm->DetachCurrentThread

Tags: multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface, pthreads

Getting error while calling (*JavaVM)->DetachCurrentThread(*JavaVM). I tried copy paste from google jni example but still unable to figure out how to solve the problem.

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
        javaVM = vm;
        JNIEnv *env;
        if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
            return JNI_ERR;
        }
        return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    }

    void *start_download( ) {
        JavaVM *jVM = javaVM;
        JNIEnv *env;
        jint res = (*jVM)->GetEnv(jVM, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
        if (res != JNI_OK) {
            res = (*jVM)->AttachCurrentThread(jVM, &env, NULL);
            if (JNI_OK != res) {
                LOGD("Failed to AttachCurrentThread, ErrorCode = %d", res);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        (*jVM)->DetachCurrentThread(jVM);
        return NULL;
    }


    void download_in_thread(const char *url, const char *path) {
        int thread_id;
        int a = 1;
        pthread_t p_thread;
        pthread_attr_t threadAttr_;

        pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr_);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&threadAttr_, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

        thread_id = pthread_create(&p_thread, &threadAttr_, start_download(url, path), (void *) &a);
    }
```

Comment: You should only call `DetachCurrentThread` if you actually called `AttachCurrentThread` (and it returned `JNI_OK`).

Comment: @Michael  AttachCurrentThread  called with return code JNI_OK.